# $x(x − N p^2)(x + N p^2)(x^2 + N^2p^4) + p $ cannot be solved by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, radicals

I wish to show if for sufficiently large integers N, and a given prime p, the polynomial $x(x − N p^2)(x + N p^2)(x^2 + N^2p^4) + p $ can be solved by radicals. I think the answer is no but I am not sure how to prove~

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Is it an equation? Did you leave out an $=$ sign somewhere?

Comment: The quintic is irreducible by Eisenstein.  So if it has three real roots then we are done.  Easy check.

Comment: Ah I see, what are the three real roots tho

Comment: You can easily show it has at least three real roots by intermediate value theorem. To see why it cannot have five real roots, compute the discriminant.

Comment: What user10354138 and pisco said. It should be clear that for very large $N$ that last term $+p$ will only move the zeros by a tiny amount (the obvious of roots of the rest of it are simple, and the derivative at those roots is quite large => the zeros won't move much.

Comment: Not unlike Cam McLeman's fine solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/130088/11619).

Comment: So let $L$ be the splitting field of that polynomial. Let $G = \operatorname{Gal}(L/Q)$. Then $5 \mid |G|$ because the polynomial is irreducible. So $G$ contains a 5 cycle. Next we show that $G$ contains a transposition too. (I'm guessing it is the restriction of complex conjugation to L but I am not sure.) Then these 2 elements generate $S_5$, so $G = S_5$. Then $S_5$ not solvable implies $L$ is not solvable. Is this right?